# Assembly 'create2' and 'new' with salt not determining the same address

Tags: solidity, remix, yul

Since solidity 0.8.0, we can now specify the salt for contract creation using new keyword

Using '**new**'

```
bytes32 _salt = bytes32("0x4");
address addr = address(new DummyContract{salt: _salt}());
```

I am getting different addresses for the same salt used in create2 which calculates address as:

> address = first 20 bytes of keccak256(0xff + address(this) + s +
> keccak256(mem[p…(p+n)))
> s = big-endian 256-bit value

using '**create2**'

```
address addr;    
bytes memory bytecode = type(DummyContract).creationCode;
    assembly {
        addr := create2(0, add(bytecode, 0x20), mload(bytecode), 4)
        if iszero(extcodesize(addr)) {
            revert(0, 0)
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"0x4"` is interpreted as a string, so the two salts are different.

```
bytes32("0x4") != 4
```